# create a 2 dimensional array of HashMaps in java

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I would like to create a 3 dimensional array in java where the first two dimensions are indices (0-100) and (0-4) and the 3rd dimension is a dictionary index (12, 18, 22, 49, etc)

How can I set this up?  I thought:

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer>[][] mem;
    mem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>[101][5];
```

But I am getting errors.  Am I approaching this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Just remove the `()` at the end because you're making an array.

Comment: You cannot create a generic array. It's not a good idea to mix arrays and generics.

Comment: Thanks Paul - Do you know how I should approach building an array like this?

Comment: Thanks alfasin - yes, I'll try a new approach if there is a way that works.

Comment: isn't it just an `int[][][]`?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Tell us what you're trying to accomplish instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a class to wrap the HashMap?

```
class Dictionary {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
}


Dictionary[][] mem = new Dictionary[101][5];
```